# guardar la imagen despues de pasarla por la funcion que les cambia el tamaño

Tags: cv2

primero me gustaria aclarar que soy muy nuevo programando y todo lo estoy aprendiendo de manera empirica.
tengo el siguiente problema:
Necesito guardar las imagenes en otra carpeta despues de cambiarles el tamaño con la funcion.
la funcion se llama maintain_aspect_ratio_resize

```
    location = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(location + '/imagenes')

filename = [f for f in glob.glob("*.jpg")]
folder = location + '/imagenes'

images = []

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))
    if img is not None:
        images.append(img)
        print(filename)
        cv2.imshow('width_100', maintain_aspect_ratio_resize(img, width=1000))# me muestra en pantalla la imagen con las medidas que necesito

        cv2.imwrite????????????   #desconozco parametros que deben ir para guardar la imagen al pasar por la funcion
```

necesito guardar esa imagen ya procesada en una carpeta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la documentación de OpenCV `imwrite` los parámetros son el nombre de entrada (filename) y la imagen a ser guardada: `cv2.imwrite(filename, image)`

Prueba creando un nombre de variable para cada iteración y guarda lo que devuelve tu función.

```py
output_name = 'loquequieras.jpg'
cv2.imwrite(output_name, maintain_aspect_ratio_resize(img, width=1000))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias,    cv2.imwrite(output_name, maintain_aspect_ratio_resize(img, width=1000)) esa linea me dio el resultado esperado (y)